# AppleScript - Iterate all open applications / process and execute a menu command

Tags: macos, macros, applescript, automator, keyboard-maestro

I am trying to write an AppleScript to be triggered by hotkey in Keyboard Maestro on MacOS

What I want to do, and please do not suggest **ANYTHING ELSE**, **such as hide all**, or hide functionality. I am looking for **minimize all** open windows functionality, ***including the animation***.

I can already do hide all.

So what I want to do is **iterate** **all** open windows, and **trigger** the menu option **Window -> Minimize** or if possible trigger minimize in a different manner.

Here is what I have so far but it is not fully working, **only partially**:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set currentProcesses to name of every application process whose visible = true
end tell

repeat with tmpProcess in currentProcesses

    tell application "System Events" to tell process tmpProcess

        set frontmost to true
        ---activate

        tell menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
            click menu item "Minimize" of menu 1
        end tell

    end tell

    delay 1

end repeat
```

Note, some applications will have a **Minimise without a z for Minimize.** . Would be good if the solution triggered some global minimize action **rather** than go through the **menu** **system**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Another working example, best so far.**

```
tell application "System Events"
    set currentProcesses to name of every application process whose visible = true
end tell

repeat with tmpProcess in currentProcesses

    tell application "System Events" to tell process tmpProcess
        set frontmost to true

        try
            tell menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1

                try
                    click menu item "Minimize" of menu 1
                on error
                    try
                        click menu item "Minimise" of menu 1
                    end try
                end try

            end tell

        end try

        delay 0.1

        set visible to false

    end tell


end repeat
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my original answer to your proposed problem, that was stated ought to work in fairly recent(*ish*) versions of MacOS:

```
    use application "System Events"


    set _P to a reference to (every process whose class of windows contains window)
    set _W to a reference to (windows of _P whose value of attribute "AXMinimized" is false)

    set value of attribute "AXMinimized" of _W to true
```

What I could have added was that, if we plug the value of each variable into the next line where it's referenced, and (for simplicity) choose to ignore the filtering used against the processes and windows, it becomes apparent that those four lines will evaluate at compile time to this single line of code:

```
    tell application "System Events" to set value of attribute "AXMinimized" of windows of processes to false
```

However, you (the OP) reported that it was slow and not always reliable, and likely didn't use an iterative method but a recursive one.

I'm awaiting details of the circumstances under which the script above was found not to be reliable.

You asked whether I could produce code of a similarly-iterative nature/structure to [one of your proposed methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49338952/9051006).

This is the script that blends the functionality of my original script with the code structure taken from yours:

```
    use application "System Events"


    get the name of every application process whose class of windows contains window

    repeat with P in the result

        get (every window of process (contents of P) whose value of attribute "AXMinimized" is false)

        repeat with W in the result

            set the value of attribute "AXMinimized" of (contents of W) to true

        end repeat  

    end repeat
```

Just as your script does, the one here explicitly iterates through all of the application processes retrieved against a filter (the filter in yours is the property `visible` for each `process`, whilst the filter in mine is collection of `window` objects of each `process`).  You are free to change if you feel the need to.

However, once inside the `repeat` loop that iterates through the `processes`, what your script neglected to do was to iterate through every window that belongs to the each process.  This is why you needed the fallback statement that sets the `visible` property to `false`, which is simply hiding the application process (something you explicitly stated in your OP that you did **not** want to do).

Without the `visible` property being set, the only other action performed is clicking the `Minimize` menu item **once** for each process.  This will trigger the *front* window (i.e. the one that currently has focus) of that application process to minimise, but all other windows belonging to it remain unaffected, meaning only **one** window for each application process will get minimised.  The rest are all just hidden by the visibility toggle.

The remedy for this was to set up a second `repeat` loop nested inside the first, which iterates through all the windows of a specific process retrieved against a filter (which, as before, I chose to be the `AXMinimized` attribute).

Then it's just a simple matter of setting the `AXMinimized` attribute for each window to `true`.

As you pointed out, one advantage of your script is that it appears to minimise the windows faster than mine.  From what I can tell, it appears, for **some** reason, that the actual minimise *animation* is swifter when triggered using the menu than when triggered through the setting of an attribute value.  So I then went ahead and created a script that doesn't try and set the attributes of the windows, but instead uses your mechanism of clicking the `Minimize` menu item:

```
    use application "System Events"


    set _P to a reference to (every application process whose visible is true)

    repeat with P in (_P as list)
        set frontmost of P to true

        set _M to (a reference to menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1 of P)
        set _minimise to (a reference to menu item "Minimise" of _M)
        set _minimize to (a reference to menu item "Minimize" of _M)


        set _W to windows of P
        set n to count _W

        if n > 0 then perform action "AXRaise" of _W's front item

        repeat n times
            if (_minimize exists) and (_minimize is enabled) then
                click _minimize
            else if (_minimise exists) and (_minimise is enabled) then
                click _minimise
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
```

This script is essentially the reworked version of yours, using the same filtering criteria for its processes (`whose visible is false`) and clicking the menu item `Minimize` (or `Minimise`) to minimise the windows.  It contains both the outside `repeat` loop for the `processes`, and the inside `repeat` loop for the `windows`.

Honestly, it's hard to say which appears to minimise windows more swiftly than the other, so I'll let you be the judge of that.

However, recalling what you stated in your original brief, you specifically asked:

- For a *"global* minimize *action rather than [to] go through the menu system"*;
- Not to offer other suggestions *"such as 'hide all', or 'hide' functionality. I am looking for [a] 'minimize-all-open-windows' functionality"*;
- To *"[include] the animation."*

Being frank about it, there's still only one solution that satisfies all of these criteria, and that's the original answer that I posted.  Other solutions you found either don't work or rely on hiding the application windows; the last contribution I provided above works, but utilises the menu items, which is not your ideal method; and the script before that, which first demonstrated the nesting of two `repeat` loops in order to iterate through both processes **and** windows can be demonstrated through inductive reasoning to be an identical script to my original solution, which, despite not have explicit iterative statements you're used to seeing in a programming language, **does** still iterate through the `process` and `window` objects behind the scenes.

You can, of course, choose whichever method you wish, as it is your project and your ultimate satisfaction that is important in the creation of a tool that you'll be the one utilising from day-to-day.  But, to give my honest and final opinion on the best method to achieve what you're setting out to do, I would strongly suggest you choose the compacted form of my first answer, which is this very elegant and simple line of code:

```
tell application "System Events" to set value of attribute "AXMinimized" of windows of processes to false
```

Comment: Thanks CJK, but it wasnt completely reliable. It was slow and I believe it is iterating recursively somehow. Could you make that work around a working sample I have? Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49338952/961018

If you add it to the iterating block. I wasn't able to modify your code to fit that. Basically I just want to set the attribute to true, but could not do that since I have process.

Comment: Can you tell me in what way is was not completely reliable ? I haven’t come across any situations where it’s failed for me, but if you can tell me how to reproduce an instance where it doesn’t work, that would be very helpful for me.   Also, can you tell me why it matters whether the method is an iterative one or a recursive one ? You said in your OP _"Would be good if the solution triggered some global minimize action rather than go through the menu system."_ That's exactly what this answer does.

Comment: However, I'm perfectly happy to try and mimic the code structure that you used in order to achieve the same outcome as my solution. I'll post the code as an update to this answer.

Comment: Hi CJK, thanks for such a lengthy detailed answer. It is now faster, however, it is not functioning properly, still but I will still accept the answer since I believe we are getting there and you deserve it. The problem with your version is that currently it appears as if windows are toggled minimized in some cases, meaning that they also open up, not only go down, some go up and then do down. The finder goes up if minimized already. I do not wish to toggle minimized, maybe you thought that was desired?

Comment: Did you try it? I am using Keyboard Maestro to trigger the script with CTRL + H.

Comment: I did try the scripts and I didn't observe the behaviour your described.  The only one of those scripts that even has the potential to do that would be the one clicking the menu item, as there is an `AXRaise` command.  However, it is impossible for the other scripts to do what you're describing as the only commands they ever issue is for `AXMinimized` to be set to `true`.  There is no toggling.  Seriously, just use the last command I gave you: `tell application "System Events" to set value of attribute "AXMinimized" of windows of processes to false` - it only minimises and does it simply.

Comment: Otherwise, I'm wondering if there's an issue with your system specifically, or if you have other programs that are interfering with the process somehow.  It's the only thing I can think of.  I'm not a fan of clicking the menu items so I personally wouldn't go for that script.  But the others work fine, and if you're having trouble that I can't physically replicate myself, then I think you have to investigate it at your end.  On an end note, I think using *Keyboard Maestro* is a great idea.  I use it and it's a brilliant piece of software.

Comment: You could actually create a *Keyboard Maestro* macro that minimises all the windows without the use of AppleScript.  Check out the action **Manipulate a Window** and use this in a control loop that iterates **For Each Item in the Running Applications Collection**.

Comment: Wierd if you are not getting the same behaviour. I should mention that I am on several desktops and one extra monitor. This only minimized on active app; https://imgur.com/a/igjk2

Comment: My script kind of does work, however not 100% an error will affect other windows

Answer (score 1):

Another slower solution found online:

```
tell application "System Events"

    repeat with appProc in (every application process whose visible is true)

        click (first button of every window of appProc whose role description is "minimize button")

    end repeat

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to at least get a working version from the one above.

I think I got some errors when the menu minimize did not exist, so I added try catch for that, and a fallback to hide.

This script should work:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set currentProcesses to name of every application process whose visible = true
end tell

repeat with tmpProcess in currentProcesses

    tell application "System Events" to tell process tmpProcess
        set frontmost to true

        try
            tell menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1

                try
                    click menu item "Minimize" of menu 1
                on error
                    try
                        click menu item "Minimise" of menu 1
                    on error 
                        --- Optional, fallback
                        set visible to false
                    end try
                end try

            end tell

        on error
            --- Optional, fallback  
            set visible to false

        end try

    end tell

    delay 0.005

end repeat
```